How to import a java package inside POM.xml?
I'm working on contract tests using Pact in a Java application with Quarkus. However, I'm running into a snag: I need to modify the requests before sending them, since authentication is required for the endpoint. I found a solution in the documentation that involves sending an authorization with each request, but the token has an expiration period. This means that the current solution is not ideal, as I have to manually generate and replace the token in the pom.xml file every time I run the tests.
To solve this problem, I found a code that theoretically allows you to import a package into pom.xml, which contains a class with a method to return the token. However, when trying to verify the contract, the request fails because it can't resolve the class.
Below is the folder structure I have in the project, note that inside the structure I have a file called OAuthTokenRequest.java, which is responsible for generating the token needed for the request. When compiling using the ./mvnw compile quarkus:dev command, the classpah is updated and from there we have the OAuthTokenRequest.class file which is what I'm trying to import into pom.xml.
.
├── ...
├── src
│   ├── main
│   │   ├── docker
│   │   │   └── ...
│   │   ├── java
│   │   │   └── ...
│   │   └── resources
│   │       └── ...
│   └── test
│       └── java
│           ├── com
│           │   └── company
│           │       ├── pact
│           │       │   ├── README.MD
│           │       │   ├── consumer
│           │       │   │   └── ContractConsumerTest.java
│           │       │   └── provider
│           │       │       └── ContractProviderTest.java
│           │       └── resources
│           │           └── ...
│           └── it
│               └── util
│                   ├── OAuthConfig.java
│                   ├── OAuthTokenRequest.java
│                   └── OAuthTokenRequestTest.java
└── target
    ├── classes
    │   └── ...
    └── test-classes
        ├── com
        │   └── company
        │       ├── pact
        │       │   ├── README.MD
        │       │   ├── consumer
        │       │   │   └── ContractConsumerTest.class
        │       │   └── provider
        │       │       └── ContractProviderTest.class
        │       └── resources
        │           └── ...
        └── it
            └── util
                ├── OAuthConfig.class
                ├── OAuthTokenRequest.class
                └── OAuthTokenRequestTest.class

Now, below is the code snippet with the "attempt" to import the method into the class to generate the token and use it in the application.
<plugin>
        <groupId>au.com.dius.pact.provider</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven</artifactId>
        <version>4.6.7</version>
        <configuration>
          <serviceProviders>
            <serviceProvider>
              <name>ConnectorsProvider</name>
              <requestFilter>
                // This is a Groovy script that adds an Authorization header to each request
                import it.util.OAuthTokenRequest
                String authHeader = "Bearer " + new OAuthTokenRequest.getToken()
                request.addHeader('Authorization', authHeader)
              </requestFilter>
              <protocol>https</protocol>
              <host>gateway.production.io</host>
              <port>443</port>
            </serviceProvider>
          </serviceProviders>
          <pactDirectory>target/pacts</pactDirectory>
          <pactBrokerUrl>http://localhost:9292</pactBrokerUrl>
          <pactBrokerUsername>pactBrokerUsername</pactBrokerUsername>
          <pactBrokerPassword>pactBrokerPassword</pactBrokerPassword>
          <trimSnapshot>true</trimSnapshot>
          <configuration>
            <pact.verifier.publishResults>true</pact.verifier.publishResults>
          </configuration>
        </configuration>
</plugin>

One detail about this section is that when I use something with an explicit token, it works perfectly.
I've tried rewriting it in other ways like:
<requestFilter>
                // This is a Groovy script that adds an Authorization header to each request
                import it.util
                String authHeader = "Bearer " + new OAuthTokenRequest.getToken()
                request.addHeader('Authorization', authHeader)
</requestFilter>

or
<requestFilter>
                // This is a Groovy script that adds an Authorization header to each request
                import it.util
                request.addHeader('Authorization', OAuthTokenRequest.getToken())
</requestFilter>

But the error like is displayed:
    Request Failed - startup failed:
Script1.groovy: 3: unable to resolve class it.util.OAuthTokenRequest
 @ line 3, column 17.
                   import it.util.OAuthTokenRequest
                   ^

1 error

I appreciate any help you can offer.

Does it work if you mark the module containing the it.util.OAuthTokenRequest as parent first in your pom? You could do this, for example, in your application.properties with quarkus.class-loading.parent-first-artifacts=igroup:itartifact.

Unfortunately, it didn't work.
I found the configuration in pom.xml:
<groupId>com.company</groupId>
<artifactId>company-management</artifactId>
<version>1.1.1</version>```

Include this line in application.properties:
`quarkus.class-loading.parent-first-artifacts=com.company:company-management` 

And update the import in pom.xml to:
```import com.company.util.OAuthTokenRequest
String authHeader = “Bearer ” + OAuthTokenRequest.getAccessToken()
request.addHeader('Authorization', authHeader)```

But the same error is displayed.

But the same error is displayed:

      Request Failed - initialization failed:
Script1.groovy: 3: unable to resolve class com.company.util.OAuthTokenRequest
 @ line 3, column 17.
                   import com.company.util.OAuthTokenRequest
                   ^

1 error```

It seems to me that it can't recognize it as a dependency, and then do the “import” because it's a class created in the same project. Perhaps if it were an external dependency it might work.

I think trying it as an external dependency is a good idea, if only for diagnostics.
